# Custom Page Layout with no left navigation

Tags: master-page, page-layout

I have created a custom master page, now I want to create a custom page layout associated with this master page with no left navigation. Any ideas? I have tried a few online solutions but not working.

Here is the code

```
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">-->
        <div xmlns="">
            <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldTextField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <!--MS:<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel">-->
                <!--MS:<PageFieldTextField:TextField FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
                <!--ME:</PageFieldTextField:TextField>-->
            <!--ME:</Publishing:EditModePanel>-->
            <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
        </div>
        <div xmlns="">
            <!--CS: Start Page Field: Page Content Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldRichHtmlField" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <!--MS:<PageFieldRichHtmlField:RichHtmlField FieldName="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" runat="server">-->
                <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><div id="ctl02_label" style="display:none">Page Content</div><div id="ctl02__ControlWrapper_RichHtmlField" class="ms-rtestate-field" style="display:inline" aria-labelledby="ctl02_label"><div align="left" class="ms-formfieldcontainer"><div class="ms-formfieldlabelcontainer" nowrap="nowrap"><span class="ms-formfieldlabel" nowrap="nowrap">Page Content</span></div><div class="ms-formfieldvaluecontainer"><div class="ms-rtestate-field">Page Content field value. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div></div></div></div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
            <!--ME:</PageFieldRichHtmlField:RichHtmlField>-->
            <!--CE: End Page Field: Page Content Snippet-->
        </div>
    <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

I fixed it using the following

```
#sidebar-nav {
                Display:none !important;
            }
            #main-content{
                Margin-left:0px !important;
            }
```

Comment: What's the Sharepoint Edition 2010 /2013 / online?

Comment: its SharePoint 2013.

Comment: I have updated the fix. the ids I am using here to display and use the full page width are actually in my master page and not in Page Layout. It was a hit and trial fix but working perfectly for me now. Thanks man for your time and effort. Really appreciate it. @M.Qassas

Comment: I updated my answer with your final code to be useful for all @bajwa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this CSS code to your Page Layout

```
    <Style> 
body #s4-leftpanel 
{ 
display: none; 
} 
.s4-ca 
{ 
margin-left: 0px; 
} 
</style>
```

For 2013 try this

```
.ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin { display: none } /* hide only quick links */
#contentBox { margin-left: 0px } /* make content take full page width */
```

After more investigation with Bajwa and based on his case he reached to final code and hope it helps all

```
#sidebar-nav {
    display:none !important;
}
#main-content{
    margin-left:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I am also here if you need more clarification

Comment: ' .ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin { display: none }'

 this works but not the content box thing so I am unable to use the page width. @M.Qassas

Comment: what's the id of content placeholder in your page layout

Comment: <div xmlns="">
                <!--CS: Start Page Field: Page Content Snippet-->
                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldRichHtmlField"

Comment: Strange div has generated no ID @M.Qassas

Comment: have you customized content  box ? also what's the structure of page layout, I can check it with you remotly , but first should you post the full front code of page layout

Comment: No its as it was generated and I have posted the Main Place holder code @M.Qassas

Comment: try this #PlaceHolderMain { margin-left: 0px } or #PlaceHolderMain { width: 100% }

Comment: Nope it does not work.

Comment: click f12 with ie browser and try to catch the div of the content that you want to increase its width ,and get it's id for example contentid then add #contentid: width:100% !important; to your style if you don't found id add style in the inline code of the div